# CSS Dropdown not working in Firefox

Tags: css, browser, input, shopify

I'm having some issues on my Shopify site getting the input selector dropdown to display properly in Firefox. The field shows and is clickable but doesn't fill with text. Works fine in Safari, Chrome, and IE.

Any idea what might be causing this?

http://stillmotionstore.com/products/storytelling-workshop-basic

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue in my testing w Firefox 25.0.1 for Mac.  Selected "Location" was added to cart as expected.

Comment: Resolved by tracking down padding issues in CSS. Shopify isn't the prettiest code I've ever seen :D

Comment: Said that already in my solution ... but it's ok, you don't have to read the answers ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

It fills with text, but the text isn't visible.

Your CSS says the following:

```
height: 24px;
padding: 1.384615385em 0.615384615em;
```

That's why there's no place for the text anymore .

#### Solutions

1. Increase the height
2. Remove the top/bottom padding
3. Use `box-sizing: border-box` so that the padding is added to the height

*Try to debug such problems with the Web Developer Tools in the future (available in all browsers), and you'll find this bugs immediately!*